# Cannot deploy the precompiled header (.gch)

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, precompiled-headers, g++4.8

Could you, please, help me with `warning: pch.hpp.gch: not used because '__STDC_IEC_559__' not defined` emerging when I am trying to deploy a gcc-generated precompiled header with boost headers?

Here is my toy model.
File `pch.hpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
```

and its complementary `pch.cpp`

```
#include "pch.hpp"
```

To produce the precompiled header, I invoke the following command:
`g++ -std=c++11 -c -x c++-header pch.cpp -o pch.hpp.gch`,
where `gcc` is of version `4.8.2`.

Now, there is the `bla.cpp` file, where I want eventually the precompiled header to be utilized:

```
#include "pch.hpp"

int main() {
   #ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__
   std::cout << "__STDC_IEC_559__ is defined by the compiler as " << __STDC_IEC_559__ << std::endl;
   #else
   std::cout << "__STDC_IEC_559__ is NOT defined by the compiler as " << __STDC_IEC_559__ << std::endl;
   #endif

   std::vector<std::string> vs {"One", "Two", "Three"};
   for (auto&& v : vs) std::cout << v << ", ";
   std::vector<int> vi {1,2,3};
   for (auto&& v : vi) std::cout << v << ", ";
   std::cout << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

I compile it with this command:
`g++ -std=c++11 -Winvalid-pch -H bla.cpp`.

The output is:

```
bla.cpp:1:19: warning: pch.hpp.gch: not used because `__STDC_IEC_559__' not defined [-Winvalid-pch]
 #include "pch.hpp"
                   ^
x pch.hpp.gch
. pch.hpp
...
```

So, the code compiles, but the precompiled header is not deployed. If I run the compiled code, I see the following output:

```
__STDC_IEC_559__ is defined by the compiler as 1
One, Two, Three, 1, 2, 3,
```

Is there a way to make use of my precompiled header? Must I generate it differently?..

Observe that if there is no boost header in my pch.hpp, i.e. only the ones from std lib, the precompiled header is deployed.

Thank you in advance!
Oleksii

Comment: Why do you deploy a precompiled header?

Comment: Is the pre-compiled header compiled with `__STDC_IEC_559__` defined? Add this define to the command line options like -D__STDC_IEC_559__. But I suppose the problem is that you have different standard libraries.

Comment: @A.A: I tried! Both as `-D__STDC_IEC_559__` and as `-D__STDC_IEC_559__=1` -- the same result.

Comment: @manni66: I want to speed up the build time of my project (~1M LOC, heavily based on boost).

Comment: The you have to generate one. But they are never deployed.

Comment: gcc: "It will be consistent
   when:
   - anything that was defined just before the PCH was generated
     is defined the same way now; and
   - anything that was not defined then, but is defined now, was not
     used by the PCH." - https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/da8dff89fa9398f04b107e388cb706517ced9505/libcpp/pch.c#L557  the macro depends on the C lib